# How do display different data in bootstrap modal using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one bootstrap modal, and multiple buttons with different id. I used ajax function to get data from another page and display to id inside modal. But when i click second button and so on it will repeatedly append data to existing modal. Where as I want only data received  from particular id. Any ways to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of append function either use empty().append() or just 
html

ie

```
$('#modal-body').empty().append("The ajax return data")


$('#modal-body').html("The ajax return data")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select one div with id and u can replace inner html by using **element.empty()** and **element.html()**

**ie.**

```
<script>
var modelBody=$('#modal-body');

$('#modelBtn1').on('click',function() {
   $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
           modelBody.empty();
          modelBody.append(html);
      }
    });
});
$('#modelBtn2').on('click',function() {
   $.ajax({
        url: "test2.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
           modelBody.empty();
           modelBody.append(html);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```